# Texture also applying to separated object

Tags: modeling, texturing, objects

I am working on creating a hammer in Blender, but I am having a problem. I separated the hammer and the handle into two separate objects, but when I apply textures to one of the items, it applies the texture to both objects. I used <kbd>P</kbd> and then *selection* to separate the two pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have the same material on both objects. You can create a new material, if you need an entirely different material.
[image: plus button]
Or click on the plus button, to make a new material from the current material. Then there will be two separate materials for your two objects.
Documentation about [materials](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Options).